# Styled-components using a prop inside of a keyframe animation

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

What's the proper way of using props inside of animation: ${styledKeyFrame} ${props.myProps}?

The issue:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
const KeyFrameTest = styled.keyframes`
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to { opacity: 1; }
`;

const StyledComponent = styled.div`
 animation: ${KeyFrameTest} 2s 4s ease-in; /* works */
 animation: ${props => `${KeyFrameTest} 2s ${props.delay} ease-in`}; /* ERROR */
 animation: ${props => `${styled.css`{KeyFrameTest}}` 2s ${props.delay} ease-in`}; /* ERROR */
`;

const PureComponent = () => <StyledComponent delay="3s" />;
export default PureComponent;
```

Comment: you have template literals inside template literals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error is happening when you try to use KeyFrames inside the `${props => }` syntax.

I don't know which version of styled-components you are using but I think this should work;

`animation: ${KeyFrameTest} 2s ${props => props.delay} ease-in`